# Title Not Appearing in Reference Section

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using the "jbact" bibliography style and after typesetting a few times, the title of my references are not showing up. [image] 
     I heard that the jbact style has a line of code to turn on titles in references but I couldn't find out how to do that precisely.

My line of code in the beginning is as follows:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}   
\begin{document}   

\TOCadd{Bibliography}   
\bibliographystyle{jbact}   
\bibliography{BIB}   

\end{document}
```

My bibtex looks like this:

```
@article{Lemaitre1997,   
author = {Lemaitre, B. and Reichhart, J.M. and Hoffmann, J.A.},   
year = {1997},   
title = {Drosophila host defense: Differential induction of antimicrobial peptide genes after infection by various classes of microorganisms},   
journal = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America},   
volume = {94},   
pages = {14614 - 14619}   
}

@article{Montenegro2005,    
author = {Montenegro, H. and Solferini, V.N. and Klaczko, L.B. and Hurst, G.D.D.},   
year = {2005},    
title = {Male-kiling Spiroplasma naturally infecting Drosophila melanogaster},    
journal = {Insect Molecular Biology},   
volume = {14},   
number = {3},   
pages = {281 - 287}   
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\nocite{TitlesOn}`, as written in line 27 of `jbact.bst`

```
% TITLES can be turned on and off!
%      Just nocite the reference TitlesOn in the paper (i.e. \nocite{TitlesOn})
%      and have a bibliography article in your database with that cite key!
% Without titles is Journal of Molecular Biology;
% With titles is Journal of Theoretical Biology.
```

**Note:**

An corresponding entry in the .bib file is necessary.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}   

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Montenegro2005,    
    author = {Montenegro, H. and Solferini, V.N. and Klaczko, L.B. and Hurst, G.D.D.},   
    year = {2005},    
    title = {Male-kiling Spiroplasma naturally infecting Drosophila melanogaster},    
    journal = {Insect Molecular Biology},   
    volume = {14},   
    number = {3},   
    pages = {281 - 287}   
}

@article{TitlesOn,
    author = "TitlesOn",
    title = "TitlesOn",
    journal = "TitlesOn",
    volume = "TitlesOn",
    comment = "If this is nocited, then titles will be turned on in JMB style",
    year = "1900"}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}   

    \nocite{TitlesOn}
    \cite{Montenegro2005}

    \bibliographystyle{jbact}   
    \bibliography{\jobname}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So I did that but the titles are still not appearing for the references.

Here is how I input the "\nocite{TitlesOn}":

 > \TOCadd{Bibliography}
 > \nocite{TitlesOn}
 > \bibliographystyle{jbact}
 > \bibliography{Thesis}

Comment: @DennisSaw See the edit, with an entry in .bib file, it works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The reference titles are now appearing. I appreciate your time and help. =)

Comment: @DennisSaw You're welcome!

Comment: Ahhh it's not working for me :( I exactly did as mentioned but it's not working.